# Stuck in Hcapture loop

Tags: python, selenium

Am using selenium and python plus 2capture API.i was able to retrieve the tokens successfully and even submit the form using js.
The form is submitted but the link keeps on reloading therefore cannot go past the hcapture loop.
here is my code:

```
def Solver(self, browser):

    WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(Ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cf-hcaptcha-container"]/div[2]/iframe')))
    captcha = CaptchaRecaptcha()
    url = browser.current_url
    code = captcha.HCaptcha(url)
    script = "let submitToken = (token) => {document.querySelector('[name=h-captcha-response]').innerText = token document.querySelector('.challenge-form').submit() }submitToken('{}')".format(code)
    script1 = (f"document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')[0].innerText='{code}'")
    print(script)
    browser.execute_script(script)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.switch_to.parent_frame()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Am using proxies in the web driver and also switching the user agent
someone, please explain what am doing wrong or what I should do to break the loop.

Comment: are you sure you send correct value? It seems you have two commmands in one line in JavaScript but you don't have `;` between commands - so it may create something strange.

Comment: did you solve this problem? i have the same issue but mine is kinda different, i  can send the code but the page cannot go past the hcaptcha page it keeps on reloading, i have tried everything, am using proxies and swithing user agents too.

Comment: when the site is behind Cloudflare the callback function is submitted in a different way, if at all anyone has found a way to call the captcha callback function it will help in submitting the generated token to the webpage. i haven't fixed this problem yet.